# Get email address of publisher given app package name

Tags: android, email, google-play, publisher

Is there a way to determine the email address of an Android Market publisher given the package name of an app they own?

I.e. Given the package name **com.acme.app** I would get back **dev@acme.com**?

And before anyone asks, I don't want to spam devs, I just need a way to prove that if a dev says they own com.acme.app they really do own it by sending them an email linked to that app and getting them to click on a confirmation link etc.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't spam us devs ;)  I already get so much junk anyways.  But confirmation email sounds like a plausible reason to me

Answer (score 1):

Via the Android SDK, no, there's no way to do that.

You can, however, reverse engineer the Android Market protocol (based on `protobuf`, IIRC) and you'll be able to fetch the dev's email this way. There are many sites out there doing just that (i.e. [cyrket](http://www.cyrket.com/m/android/)) and I bet you can find some documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sam

[Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) is designed just for that.

Thank them.

Comment: Is this reliable though? It mentions you need a Google Account to use this API. What happens if you have heavy use of the API, is it likely that Google will block the account?